# "Failed to create target binding for to" in MvvmCross .dialog

Tags: ios, mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

So I'm playing around with MvvmCross and Monotouch.Dialog in iOS and I am experiencing a binding issue when I do something that is pretty trivial - and in fact done almost verbatim in one of Stuart's n+1 videos.

Given the following view:

```
[Register("FirstView")]
public class FirstView : MvxDialogViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var bindings = this.CreateInlineBindingTarget<FirstViewModel>();

        Root = new RootElement("Example Root")
        {

            new Section("Search")
            {
                new EntryElement("SearchString", "Search String").Bind(bindings, vm => vm.SearchString)
            }
        };

    }
}
```

and this ViewModel:

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private string _searchString = "search string";
    public string SearchString
    {
        get
        {
            return _searchString;
        }
        set
        {
            _searchString = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchString);
        }
    }

}
```

When navigate to this view,  I get the following errors from Mvx:

```
2013-08-22 14:44:51.766 TestApp[11581:c07] MvxBind:Error:  2.02 Empty binding target passed to MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry
[0:] MvxBind:Error:  2.02 Empty binding target passed to MvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry
[0:] 
2013-08-22 14:44:51.869 TestApp[11581:c07] MvxBind:Warning:  2.10 Failed to create target binding for to 
[0:] MvxBind:Warning:  2.10 Failed to create target binding for to
```

I'm not exactly sure why the binding is failing.  If I set a break point in the "Get" for SearchString, I do in fact see it getting hit.  Changing the value of the Entry Element however does not trigget the "Set".

Any thoughts?

Comment: From the `Empty binding target`, my only immediate thought is have you changed setup to inherit from `MvxTouchDialogSetup`?

Comment: Ahhh!  That is indeed what I missed.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stuart's guess is correct: 
All I needed to do was change my Setup class to inherit from **MvxTouchDialogSetup**.